# Return a key when a function returns true

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I've no idea what to call this, so I called it `Classify` since that's how I use it.

Basically, the idea is to pass a `Dictionary<TResult, Func<TValue, bool>>` which is evaluated for an input, and the first `Func<TValue, bool>` returning true will return the `TResult` key.

The intention is to make this a generic extension method.

```
public TResult Classify<TValue, TResult>(TValue input, Dictionary<TResult, Func<TValue, bool>> classifications)
{
    foreach (var classification in classifications)
    {
        if (classification.Value.Invoke(input))
        {
            return classification.Key;
        }
    }

    return default(TResult);
}
```

Pretty simple, but pretty useful (for me at least) as well.

Usage:

```
<td class='<%#Classify(((ApiBatchLog)Container.DataItem).RequestsPerSecond, new Dictionary<string, Func<double, bool>> { ["good"] = x => x >= 3, ["neutral"] = x => x > 2, ["bad"] = x => true }) %>'>
    <%#((ApiBatchLog)Container.DataItem).RequestsPerSecond.ToString("0.00") %>
</td>
```

Comment: Why not use a ternary expression like `x >= 3 ? "good" : x > 2 ? "neutral" : "bad"` instead? It's more succinct, faster and even more readable in my opinion (having the condition in front of the result looks more natural to me, and there are no `= x =>` in there that make the actual conditions harder to spot).

Comment: Way too much code mixed into your aspx if you ask me.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Because `x` doesn't exist on the front end, so I have to case twice to make it work: `((ApiBatchLog)Container.DataItem).RequestsPerSecond >= 3 ? "good" : ((ApiBatchLog)Container.DataItem).RequestsPerSecond >= 2 ? "neutral" : "bad"`. I want to avoid the double-casting (or more, depending on thresholds and conditions).

Comment: In that case, what about `TOutput Classify<TInput, TOutput>(TInput input, Func<TInput, TOutput> translate)`, which can be called like `Classify(((ApiBatchLog)Container.DataItem).RequestsPerSecond, (x) => x >= 3 ? "good" : x >= 2 ? "neutral" : "bad")`?

Comment: Dictionary is not ordered. You can achieve the same syntax with a custom `Add` method and a custom class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three small things:

1. A `Func<TValue, bool>` is more commonly known as a `Predicate<TValue>`
2. You're mapping  ... the "wrong" way round. You're mapping a predicate-match to a value. Your dictionary should reflect that. I strongly suggest you use a `Dictionary<Predicate<TValue>, TResult>` instead to be more "semantically correct" (or at least semantically predictable)
3. Your Dictionary iteration is not guaranteed to always yield the same results as is. Dictionary doesn't generally have a guaranteed iteration order. Instead you should consider using a `SortedDictionary`

Comment: The first makes complete sense, the second does as well but isn't what I want (I like the `string` => `Predicate<T>` mapping), and the third should (I would think) be fixed by LINQ `FirstOrDefault` mentioned in Mat's Mug's answer.

Comment: @EBrown: `FirstOrDefault` depends on the order of the collection, so using it won't fix issue #3.

Answer (score 8):

Needs more LINQ:

```
return classifications.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Value.Invoke(input)).Key;
```

This has the advantage (IMO) of highlighting the fact that you're discarding all but the first match (note that iteration order is not guaranteed!).

`Classify` doesn't really convey the fact that you're returning a `Key` from a dictionary. Seems `FindKey` would be a much better name.

A generic extension method seems like a good idea -  call your source `source`, and stick to `TKey` and `TValue`:

```
public static TKey FindKey<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, Func<TValue, bool>> source, TValue input)
{
    return source.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Value.Invoke(input)).Key;
}
```

That one-liner makes use of the fact that `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` is a `struct` (and therefore can't be `null`), so you can just return `.Key` and that will be `default(TKey)`.

Comment: In this context probably `GetClass` would be even better.

Comment: @t3chb0t I'm making it an all-access generic method.

Comment: You are calling `FirstOrDefault`, but forgetting to set the default to `default(T)`, and therefore have the potential to throw an NRE when you try to access `Key`.

Comment: @Hosch250 `T` is a `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` which is a value type and therefore can't be `null`; assuming the `Func` delegate won't throw, this code couldn't throw a NRE if it tried.

Comment: Oh, OK.  Would you like me to try that?  Set `classifications` to `null` for starters.

Comment: @Hosch250 lol fair enough, the extension method assumes `source` isn't `null` - but then I'd *expect* a NRE to be thrown in that case... I meant about accessing the `.Key` directly wrt `FirstOrDefault` :-)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about the design. It's not really testable, reusable and maintainable. I could imagine that something like this could be more reliable:

```
interface IEvaluator<TResult, TValue>
{   
    TResult Evaluate(TValue value);
}

class RequestsPerSecondEvaluator : IEvaluator<string, double>
{
    public string Evaluate(double value)
    {
        if (value >= 3) return "good";
        if (value > 2) return "neutral";
        return "bad";
    }
}
```

and

```
<td class='<%#new RequestsPerSecondEvaluator().Evaluate(((ApiBatchLog)Container.DataItem).RequestsPerSecond))
```

Especially I'm not a fan of any *business-logic* in the markup.

Comment: This is literally the opposite of what I want. I *want* the conditions on the markup side, so that if I change conditions I don't have to redeploy the entire binary.